# RCP Building for mac fails using Delta Pack

Tags: eclipse, macos, swt, rcp

I am having troubles building my RCP Application for Mac using the Delta Pack. I have **Delta Pack 3.7.2** installed and configured right (inserted into a target platform ) and the Building part completes just perfectly.

When I try to run the build app on my windows(Dev PC) it works fine. But when I zip the Mac version and try to run it on my mac, then it fails on every version I try:

- Cocoa 32b,
- Cocoa 64b,
- Carbon etc

The app won't open and I don't get an error message.

Is there a way to get an error message anyway? Has anyone had this problem before?

Comment: is there a console (either the MacOS console or something built into Eclipse) that might give you good hints to work with?

Comment: Well i am not the mac specialist so I how can you start a .app in the console?

Comment: Go to "Terminal.app" (it's in "`/Applications/Utilities`") and then "`cd`" to the location where your app is (assuming you un-zipped it). If it's an traditional MacOS application package, you can further "`cd`" into it's "`Contents/MacOS`" folder and *that* is the binary you can run from the command line.

Comment: Aye, did that... got me some errors indeed! Got it nearly fixed... First I had to chmod 755 the eclipse runnable... before it would even start.. then I had some DB issues

Answer (score 1):

When you build for a mac on a windows machine you should not build directly to a directory. Instead you should build to an archive. Then put this archive on the mac and expand it there. Then everything should work